# Drawing overlay view on top of a web view

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiwebview, drawing

I am trying to make an app that can annotate PDFs.

What I have done, is add the PDF through a UIWebview, so my main UIViewControllerhas a UIWebView Delegate.

What I am trying to do is put my drawing layer, which is a UIView over the top of my PDF view.

I have tried setting the background colour to "clearColour" and the opaque property to no, I still get a weird affect.

I think the issue might be because of drawing a bitmap onto the UIView, but I would still like some insight, or an example if one exists.

Thanks.

This is an image of the problem, the little white band at the top is the PDF, the white box is the UIView which I am drawing on.

The code I used for the "drawing code" is here, see "SmoothedBIView"

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/

[image]

Comment: If you're having drawing problems you should include your drawing code, or at least a detailed description of what your drawing code does. How else can we know where you're going wrong? A picture of the "weird effect" would help, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, just noticed you had two questions. Again maybe [this project](https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View) can help you.

Comment: Hey, Im not having issues drawing, or displaying a PDF - its doing both at the same time :) - other question isn't really a duplicate - this question asks for a solution to a specific approach where as my other asks for "the best" approach overall

Comment: Well, I don't really have time to go through your code, maybe you could try adding the above projects UIView on top of your pdf and see what happens? If it's still not displayed properly, you could have a look into the view hierarchy and the opaque properties again..